# mysql SUM columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sum

I'm trying to `SUM` multple columns from a table using the follow query.

```
$res1 = $db->prepare('SELECT sum(kill) as kill, 
   SUM(death) as death, SUM(assist)as assit FROM eventgame GROUP BY player');
$res1->execute();
while ($row = $res1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo '.$row['player'] .$row['kill'] .$row['death'] .$row['assit'].';}
```

what I'm trying to do is get the total from each player, like:

> PLAYER   | kill   |   death  | assit
>
> player1  |   10   |      5   | 26
>
> player2  |    5   |     10   | 35

I have been trying this for the last 2 days or so before come here ask for help.

I'm using PDO to connect to my DB.

Answer (score 3):

You really are not preparing a statement with bound parameters, as much as you are running a query. From the mysql-side of things, try something like

```
SELECT player, sum(kill) as kill, SUM(death) as death, SUM(assist) as assist 
FROM eventgame 
GROUP BY player
order by player
```

You group by the column or columns that are not in the aggregate functions (like sum avg count min max etc)